# Why "China Plate" isn't said Chinese plate?

Tags: meaning

Why we don't say Chinese plate rather than China plate, like the American food or Iranian carpet?

Example: China plates are usually stronger than the other ones, but it doesn't mean that they never break.

Comment: "China" here refers to *a fine white or translucent vitrified ceramic material*. A plate made of china.

Comment: I think that @Justin is correct if you're talking about porcelain. Apparently there is also a tectonic plate with that name. Many nouns (such as "plate") can be modified by adjectives (such as "Chinese") or other nouns (such as "China"), and the reason isn't always clear (unless you can actually dig into the etymology). There is a discussion of that issue here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#Use_when_an_adjectivally_inflected_alternative_is_available

Comment: Please post the full context via an example sentence or paragraph.

Comment: If the plate was actually made in China, it _would_ be a Chinese plate!

Comment: @mjjf it's added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of "china" is "a type of porcelain".

"China" is short for "chinaware".  This is a rather old construction of a word.  Compare with "delftware" or "staffordware" (meaning pottery made in Delft, or Staffordshire, respectively).

But chinaware was the most expensive and sought after type of pottery in the 18th century. So "chinaware plate" became shortened to "china plate".  Note that in this use the word "china" isn't a proper noun, and isn't capitalised. It is a common noun.  It is also correct to say "This china plate was made in England", or even "It's English china".  The relationship between the place and the product is now broken. The only connection between china and China is historical.

Comment: I never said otherwise.

Comment: James, but you didn't say it can be used on its own. Why not just give an example?

Comment: The question doesn't ask if it is a noun, or if it can be used on its own.  It didn't seem relevant. But it doesn't hurt, so I've added an example

Comment: The OP didn't know at all. So, an example is good.